# Buttons (and other clips) getting pixeled or distorsioned when scaling down in flash

Tags: flash, air, smoothing, lossless-compression, pixelate

Our images in buttons and other components are getting pixeled or distorsionated, when scaling down or up the whole movie.

Left without scaling, right with scaling down
[image: Left without scaling, right with scaling down]

We have this properties over each image of the movie:

[image]

Any idea what could it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. How do you scale the movieclip?

Comment: Hi the whole movie is being scaled.

For example running from the project and resizing the testing running swf. (After control+enter) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bitmaps are set to smooth, it could be your stage's quality is set too low.

```
stage.quality = StageQuality.MEDIUM;
```

Is usually a good setting for bitmap smoothing.